# What does くり mean?

Tags: words

What does くり mean after the stem of ます form?

> いやいやいや、わかりま**くり**でしょ。優ちゃんが読んでるその本にも書いてあるしさ。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word is 「まくり」 and not 「くり」.

> 「Verb in 連用形{れんようけい} "continuative form" + まく**る**」

means:

> "to do a lot of", "to (verb) like crazy", "to (verb) very easily and/or completely", etc.

「まく**り**」 is the noun form of the verb 「まく**る**」.

Thus, 「わかりまくりでしょ」 means "You get/understand it completely, dontcha?"

> "Nah, nah, nah, you get it completely, dontcha?  (Coz) It's discussed in the book you're reading, too."

(I am assuming that 優ちゃん is the name of the listener.)